# Error inserting dataframe into SQL server using Python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sql-insert

I am inserting into a SQL server table a dataframe taken from an Excel File using Python. However, I am getting the following error:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Python/Task1.py", line 19, in 
cursor.execute('''
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 16 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision. (8023) (SQLExecDirectW)')**

Please see below my syntax:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

#Import the Excel File into the DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Diego\Documents\1.Laboral\Jas-Ole\Revenue Management\Reservation_stats_REF.xls')

#Connect Python to SQL Server
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};''Server=DIEGO\SQLEXPRESS;''Database=Auxiliary;''Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

#Delete a Table data in SQL Server using Python
for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                DELETE FROM Auxiliary.dbo.Res_statsTEMP
                ''')

#Insert a Table data in SQL Server using Python
for row in df.itertuples():
        cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO Auxiliary.dbo.Res_statsTEMP 
                (Confirmation_number,Status,Name,Telephone,Adults,Children,Baby,Start_date,End_date,Stays,
                Reservation_date,Property,Covid_payment,Charged_amount,Revenue,Email,Origin,Market_code,
                Transport) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                ''',
                row.Confirmation_number,row.Status,row.Name,row.Telephone, row.Adults,row.Children, 
                row.Baby,row.Start_date, row.End_date, row.Stays,row.Reservation_date,row.Property,
                row.Covid_payment,row.Charged_amount, row.Revenue,row.Email,row.Origin,row.Market_code,
                row.Transport)      
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

I believe is something related with the datatypes in the dataframe not matching with the datatypes in the SQL Server table:

Confirmation_number            object
Status                         object
Name                           object
Telephone                      object
Adults                          int64
Children                        int64
Baby                            int64
Start_date             datetime64[ns]
End_date               datetime64[ns]
Stays                           int64
Reservation_date       datetime64[ns]
Property                       object
Covid_payment                 float64
Charged_amount                 object
Revenue                       float64
Email                          object
Origin                         object
Market_code                    object
Transport                      object

The ones that don't match are the ones saying "object" but based on Python datatypes, this is a "string" in SQL which matches with my Varchar255 in the table.

I am not sure why this error is rising in the terminal. I hope you can assist

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you pass your parameters as a tuple

```
cursor.execute(
            '''
            INSERT INTO Auxiliary.dbo.Res_statsTEMP 
            (Confirmation_number,Status,Name,Telephone,Adults,Children,Baby,Start_date,End_date,Stays,
            Reservation_date,Property,Covid_payment,Charged_amount,Revenue,Email,Origin,Market_code,
            Transport) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
            ''',
            (row.Confirmation_number,row.Status,row.Name,row.Telephone, row.Adults,row.Children, 
            row.Baby,row.Start_date, row.End_date, row.Stays,row.Reservation_date,row.Property,
            row.Covid_payment,row.Charged_amount, row.Revenue,row.Email,row.Origin,row.Market_code,
            row.Transport)
            )
```

and change your DataFrame columns object type to string type with

```
df[['Confirmation_number','Status','Name','Telephone','Property','Charged_amount','Email','Origin','Market_code','Transport']].astype(str)
```